# tf.data.Dataset.from_generator not supporting uint16, uint32?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a HDF5 file with a `uint16` dataset that I would like to read data from using Tensorflow's [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets). I am using [`from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) to yield items from the HDF5 file as needed. However, I am getting an error about an unsupported data type.

Edit: I initially thought the problem had to do with how I am using the HDF5 but it is possible to reproduce it with an even simpler case as mentioned in the comments.

The following code replicates the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class generator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self):
        yield np.random.random_integers(0,1000).astype(np.uint16)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator(), 
    tf.uint16, 
    tf.TensorShape(None))

next_element = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            my_data = sess.run(next_element)
            print(my_data)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

I obtain the following error trace as the software crashes:

```
2018-03-22 22:53:07.803119: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1190] Unimplemented: Unsupported numpy type 4
2018-03-22 22:53:07.803235: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1202] OP_REQUIRES failed at iterator_ops.cc:870 : Unimplemented: Unsupported numpy type 4
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_INT64], Tout=[DT_UINT16], token="pyfunc_1"](arg0)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datatype_problem.py", line 30, in <module>
    my_data = sess.run(next_element)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow-remote/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 905, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow-remote/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow-remote/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1355, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/username/tensorflow-remote/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1374, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: Unsupported numpy type 4
     [[Node: PyFunc = PyFunc[Tin=[DT_INT64], Tout=[DT_UINT16], token="pyfunc_1"](arg0)]]
     [[Node: IteratorGetNext = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[<unknown>], output_types=[DT_UINT16], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator)]]
```

The part `Unimplemented: Unsupported numpy type 4` seems to indicate that the data type `uint16` might not be supported.

@KRish suggest in the comments one possible workaround which seems to work: replace the output datatype in the `from_generator` call by for example `tf.int64`. This works, but will potentially lead to more typecasting required in the rest of the pipeline. They also mention [this code on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0c18589a71dba03edbaaca67a40815006ed26043/tensorflow/python/lib/core/py_func.cc#L109) might explain the lack of support. There are also other types such as `uint32` and `uint64` missing from there.

Is there a reason these unsigned integer types are not supported here? What would be the recommended workaround to be able to use `tf.uint16` type with `Dataset.from_generator`?

Comment: Weird. It doesn't seem to be an h5py issue, I replaced the h5py code with a generator that just returned np.uint16 values and got the same error. Changing to np.uint8 and tf.uint8 works fine. The error seems to be implying that the value coming in is of type int64 instead of uint16- changing it tf.uint16 to tf.int64 worked, but I don't quite understand why. Perhaps np.uint16 is somehow different from tf.uint16?

Comment: I think I may have identified the problem- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0c18589a71dba03edbaaca67a40815006ed26043/tensorflow/python/lib/core/py_func.cc#L109 doesn't implement a case for NPY_UINT16. This should throw an error, but for some reason it defaults to tf.int64. I can open a pull request tomorrow if one of the devs or someone else doesn't have an answer or some other insight.

Comment: @KRish It looks like some other types, e.g., NPY_UINT32 are missing as well.

Comment: yes, I noticed NPY_UNIT32 and NPY_UINT64 were not implemented- perhaps there is some good reason why- one of the devs might be able to explain it. In the meantime, you can maybe use tf.int64 or tf.int16 in the from_generator function (both worked for me).

Comment: @KRish thanks for the tip! It seems like a strange omission so maybe there indeed is some reason behind it, would be great to know!

Comment: `np.int16` appears to be the same, I see `Unimplemented: Unsupported numpy type 8`.